# how would I change the value of location.href programmatically using vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I have this button like so:

`<button type="button" class="play-now-button" onclick="location.href='www.yahoo.com'">Play Now</button>`

however, I'd like to change the value of `location.href` using vanilla js.  What I have below isn't working.  I looked online and saw some suggestions but to no avail.  What am I doing wrong?

```
let playButton = document.getElementsByClassName("play-now-button")[0];
playButton.onclick.location.href = "www.google.com";
```

I've also tried:

```
playButton.onclick = function() {
   this.location.href = "www.google.com"
}
```

But none of those work.  I need to use the button.  I don't want to use an `<a>` tag because I want to maintain the styling.  I've also tried to nest an `a` tag inside the `button` but also to no avail.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: so you want that on click of the playbutton it redirect you to google.com

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.location.href = "www.blabla.com";

// or

window.location.href = "/mysite/some-page";
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work here because this code is inside iframe, use it in your main document it will work there.

```js
let playButton = document.getElementsByClassName("play-now-button")[0];
playButton.onclick = function(e) {
   window.location.assign('https://www/google.com')
}
```

```html
<button class="play-now-button">Open Another Link</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` will be the HTMLButtonElement when the handler is executed.

You need to make a small change to your code.

`playButton.onclick = function() {
   window.location.href = "www.google.com"
}`